# can't install German language

Tags: joomla, language

I followed the description as in: https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/translation/-/wikis/Administrator-Guide to install additional languages (Joomla).

This is what my directories look like:
[image]

and:
[image]

Nevertheless, I only see 'English (US)' as possible language in the Administration console.

What can I do to switch to German (no other language needed)?

Thx,
Stefan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the l10n and SQL folder inside `/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm` folder.

You will need to move all the folder `httpdocs/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/` to `httpdocs/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/`

Comment: THAT makes sense! ;-)
Thank you, that solved the issue!